# How do you effectively debug overfull \hbox warnings?

Tags: boxes, warnings, debugging

I still haven't found out how to effectively solve `Overfull \hbox (0.80913pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active` warnings.

For instance, this piece of latex generates such a warning and I am stumped why:

```
\newcommand\Header{%
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\contactinfo}
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%
\hfill\includegraphics[height=25pt]{logo}}}\par\vskip1ex%
\par\ColTopRule\par}
```

`\contactinfo` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\contactinfo{\fontsize{8pt}{8}\selectfont\headerfnt Streetname 12324 \\ PostalCode City \\ +31655555555555}
```

Error:

```
*geometry detected driver: pdftex*
<logo.eps>
Overfull \hbox (0.80913pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 [] 
[1] <logo.eps>
Overfull \hbox (0.80913pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 [] 
[2] <logo.eps>
Overfull \hbox (0.80913pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 [] 
[3] <logo.eps>
Overfull \hbox (0.80913pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 []
```

Expected output is:

```
Streetname 12324                                       here comes
PostalCode City                                          the logo
+31655555555555                                     right aligned
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I mean, both boxes have a length of `0.5\textwidth`, the text is obviously smaller than this, as is the logo. How come it still generates such a warning? And how can I found out why?

Comment: You need to escape spaces with `%`. E.g. `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%`

Comment: did that: `\newcommand\Header{%
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\contactinfo}
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%
\hfill\includegraphics[height=25pt]{logo}}}\par\vskip1ex%
\par\ColTopRule\par}`

error remains

Comment: hard to see in the comment formatting but you still have a space  before each of the \parbox commands in that comment

Comment: weird, I removed all spaces. To no avail

Comment: `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` doesn't care if you put something larger than `\textwidth` in it. So I doubt that the problem is from the content. I guess that you either have a additional space at the place where you use your `\Header` command or a non-zero `\parfillskip` value. Make a complete example.

Comment: what is the definition of `\ColTopRule`? a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  always helps...

Comment: what's the best way to provide a concrete or MWE within a comment when comment formatting doesn't render my examples with newlines? Pastebin?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To answer the general question about how to debug the box warnings add

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
```

or if that is too much information

```
\showboxdepth=5
\showboxbreadth=5
```

and then whenever TeX is showing box information in the log it will show you a representation of the contents of the box.

Comment: Could you please tell where should I add the above commands?

Comment: @ShraySharan anywhere before the offending code, the preamble of the document for example.

Comment: Overfull \hbox (4.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set - 1.0
.\glue 3.0 plus 1.5 minus 1.0
.\glue 3.0 plus 1.5 minus 1.0
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 430.00739fil
....\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set 215.0037fil []
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

Comment: I have messages as in the above comment in the log file. I dont understand their meaning. Also when I click on the warning, it doesn't redirect me the line of code that has the warning.. Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: @ShraySharan you have something (most likely in the page head) that is 4pt wider than the page.

Comment: Interestingly enough, inserting this in my preamble reduced the number of bad boxes from 24 to 1.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio the above commands won't change  the number of warnings, just change the format of the warnings that tex gives

Comment: I think package `microtype` solved my instance of this warning, but I not learned enoush in *TeX to provide a reasoning or proof.

Comment: @tukusejssirs microtype extends tex's justification algorithms so you will get fewer instances of bad linebreaks (usually) although that doesn't seem related to this question really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I had a warning that the OP described, but when I added `\usepackage{microtype}`, this warning disappeared.

Comment: @tukusejssirs sure that is to be expected.

Comment: Is there any guide on reading the log of this command?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa the texbook has the full detail but is not free for a free version see `texdoc texbytopic` section 6.7

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways:

- The answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493311/250119 shows how to append a message at the end of overfull hboxes.

  The output looks something like this:

  [image]
- The answer in [How to visualize the underfull box in final output PDF files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21139/250119) similarly uses Lua callback to mark underfull `vbox`es in red. It is probably adaptable.
- `lua-visual-debug` package can be used to look at the boxes, although unfortunately this by itself does not show which box is overfull.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to look at the code and know. For example, the code presented in the question:

```
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{              % it is \hbox to\hsize and it starts with space here
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\contactinfo}  % it creates a box with 0.5\hsize width and there is second space here
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%              % it creates a box with 0.5\hsize width 
\hfill\includegraphics[height=25pt]{logo}}}
```

Two boxes with 0.5`\hsize` plus two spaces is more than one `\hsize`.