# How to perform an action when an overfull or underfull box is encountered?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, typography, warnings

For a revision of a rather long document (based on `book` class), I'd like to not only mark overfull hboxes (easy thanks to the `draft` class option) but also to add a specific TOC entry (say "Look at the overfull hbox at this page!") when such an overfull hbox is encountered.

Moreover, I'd like to perform similar action for overfull vboxes, and underfull hboxes and vboxes.

I had a look at *The LaTeX2e Sources* and at the *Standard Document Classes for LaTeX2e* but couldn't find any way to perform an action when an overfull or underfull box is encountered. Do you see how this would be possible?

Comment: I accept that you  want visual mark-up but, of course, you can just read the log file:)

Comment: luatex is your only practical option here I suspect (or as Andrew says parse the log file)

Comment: @Andrew The log file isn't an option because the document has to be revised also by people who don't know anything to LaTeX (so imagine I send them the log file and I tell them to look at it ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm very surprised: impossible to add a hook to the warning (La)TeX issues when an (over|under)full box is encountered?

Comment: no that warning isn't from latex it is from the guts of tex-the-program and not under the control of the macro layer, it's not even easy to tell from tex macros that a paragraph resulted in an overfull box at all, never mind change the behaviour if one is there.

Comment: adding hooks to tex internals is more or less a description of luatex of course, so in lua you do get callbacks and can write lua functions that are called as tex packages boxes that can add additional debugging.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. Unfortunately, I don't know anything to Lua callbacks. Hence I'm not against a LuaTeX answer from LuaTeX insiders :)

Comment: no time today but have a look at the lua-visual-debug package that probably gives an overload of information for your use but shows how luatex can give a lot more info. anyway that might give  a hint for someone to make an answer:-)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé instead of sending the log file you can do the parsing first and send them the result. This way you aren't required to run the document with luatex if that is a problem for one or the other reason. (the parsing could be done even by TeX or lua as a separate step but only requiring the TeX installation then).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach That's what I did but, for next issues of this document, I hoped another, more automatic, solution that doesn't involve me. Indeed, I didn't test a `lualatex` compilation and (1) luckily, it works like a charm, (2) unluckily, it leads to line breaks frequently different from the ones that occur with `pdflatex` (maybe because of the `microtype` package) so, unfortunately,  it wouldn't be relevant to point the (over|under)full boxes encountered with `pdflatex`. Okay a solution would be to use only `lualatex`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This luatex-only answer inserts some code (that I stole from the chickenize package) to insert text as a list of glyph and glue nodes at the end of any box that the hpack callback reports as over or under full.

It's just a sketch really but more or less works on this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\directlua{
GLYPH = node.id("glyph")
GLUE  = node.id("glue")
%
function hpackshow (indicator,num,nd,f,l)
print('HPACK: ' .. indicator .. ' ' .. num)
if (indicator == 'overfull' or indicator == 'underfull' ) then
if (indicator == 'overfull') then
local pt = num / 65536.0
str = string.format("| overfull \@percentchar #.2fpt",pt)
else
str = string.format("| underfull badness " .. num)
end
nds = {}
nds[0]=node.new(GLYPH,1)
    for i = 1,string.len(str) do
      nds[i] = node.new(GLYPH,1)
      nds[i].font = font.current()
      nds[i-1].next = nds[i]
    end

    j = 1
    for s in string.utfvalues(str) do
      local char = unicode.utf8.char(s)
      nds[j].char = s
      if unicode.utf8.match(char,"\@percentchar s") then
        nds[j] = node.new(GLUE)
        nds[j].width = space
        nds[j].shrink = shrink
        nds[j].stretch = stretch
      end
      j = j+1
    end
return nds[0]
end
end
%
luatexbase.add_to_callback('hpack_quality',hpackshow,'my hpack logger')
}
\begin{document}

somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext 
somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext 
somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext 
somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext 
somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext somelongtextsomelongtext 


\begin{minipage}{5cm}\fussy\parfillskip=0pt
onetwothree onetwothree
onezztzzzwothree onetwothree
onetwothree onetzzzzzwothree
onetzzzzwothree onetwothree
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite nice! Would be even nicer :) if we could have a table of (over|under)full (h|)vboxes, with the corresponding page numbers and, as you did here, with the corresponding length/badness.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé that's probably easy to to, just needs to store the value in some global lua table as you go past and then dump it out at the end (in the log or in the document?)