# Overfull \hbox (124.69516pt too wide) in paragraph in a table

Tags: warnings, debugging

I'm making a table with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Answer}
\author{That's me}
\date{March 2018}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Instruction & Mode & \#cycles without prefetch & \#cycles with prefetch & \#memory accesses \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
ADD $R_i$ expr & 6 & 87837 & 787 & pototo \\ 
LOAD $R_i$ [expr] & 7 & 78 & 5415 & pototo\\
XOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 778 & 7507 & pototo\\
STOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 18744 & 7560 & pototo \\
BEQ disp (not taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo \\ 
BEQ disp (taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But getting the following error \hbox (124.69516pt too wide) and therefore the table isn't showing.

I checked these two questions but the solution didn't work for me. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111948/148199) and [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51762/how-do-you-effectively-debug-overfull-hbox-warnings)

Edit: the whole code so that Phelype Oleinik can check it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Answer}
\author{That's me}
\date{March 2018}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\tblmultiline}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\maketitle

\textbf{2.1.b)} normal text
\\

\textbf{2.1.c)} Normal text
\\

\textbf{2.1.d)} Normal text and some code. Here's the code: \\

SigmaA $<-$ IR.val(Bbus) \\
\{ SigA = IR.val \} \\ 
SigmaR $<-$ RAM[SigmaA] \\
\{ SigA = IR.val, SigR = RAM \} \\
SigmaW, CC $<-$ RA(Abus) + SigmaR(Bbus), ALU.cc \\
\{ SigA = IR.val, SigR = RAM[IR.val], CC = ALU.cc, SigW = RA+RAM[IR.val]\} \\
RAM[SigmaA] $<-$ SigmaW \\
\{RAM[IR.val] = RAM[IR.val] + RA \} \\


\textbf{2.3.c)} 


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Instruction & Mode & \tblmultiline{\#cycles\\without\\prefetch} &     \tblmultiline{\#cycles\\with\\prefetch} & \tblmultiline{\#memory\\accesses} \\    [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
ADD $R_i$ expr & 6 & 87837 & 787 & pototo \\ 
LOAD $R_i$ [expr] & 7 & 78 & 5415 & pototo\\
XOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 778 & 7507 & pototo\\
STOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 18744 & 7560 & pototo \\
BEQ disp (not taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo \\ 
BEQ disp (taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'm using sharelatex.com if that's relevant at all.

Comment: An `overfull hbox` mean that something is extrapolating the document margins. In this case, your table is too wide because of its headers.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik how do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "overfull hbox" basically means that something is extrapolating the text margins, in this case, the table. To save it you can increase the limit of extrapolation that TeX allows (not recommended), or shrink the faulty line (table) to fit in the margins.

Your table is too wide because of its headers. I used a `\tblmultiline` comman to split them into multiple lines to fit in the page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Answer}
\author{That's me}
\date{March 2018}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\tblmultiline}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\maketitle
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Instruction & Mode & \tblmultiline{\#cycles\\without\\prefetch} & \tblmultiline{\#cycles\\with\\prefetch} & \tblmultiline{\#memory\\accesses} \\[0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
ADD $R_i$ expr & 6 & 87837 & 787 & pototo \\ 
LOAD $R_i$ [expr] & 7 & 78 & 5415 & pototo\\
XOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 778 & 7507 & pototo\\
STOR $R_i$ [expr] & 545 & 18744 & 7560 & pototo \\
BEQ disp (not taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo \\ 
BEQ disp (taken) & 88 & 788 & 6344 & pototo\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied your solution but it still doesn't work. Am i missing something?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji What doesn't work? I compiled the exmaple code and there are no warnings. If you're using the table in a large document, did you remember to copy the line that says `\newcommand{\tblmultiline}...`?

Comment: Yes i did but oddly enough the table is not visible but i'm getting no warnings

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji Very strange... Can you share the whole code you're using for me to see why the table isn't showing? If not, try removing parts of the code until there is enough to show the problem.

Comment: I will edit the question to insert the whole code.

Comment: Can you take a look now?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji The definition of `\tblmultiline` in the code you posted was missing a `]`. I edited your question to fix it. Other than that, it works fine. [Here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lt0m.png)