# How to solve `Underfull \vbox' and `Overfull \hbox' warning?

Tags: warnings

[image]

I got some warnings like this, but the display of my PDF seems ok, nothing wrong can be found in the report, I wonder what the problems are?
I've read some answers here but still no idea, can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: you have not really shown any information that will allow anyone to help you , but some of these must be clearly visible, the paragraph starting at line 755 of the source has a line sticking 33pt so almost half an inch or a centimetre or so into the right margin

Comment: You should load package `showframe` (or, if you use `geometry`, add the option `showframe`)  to visually check.

Comment: Thank you, I've just solved it.

Comment: You can also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21139/how-to-visualize-the-underfull-box-in-final-output-pdf-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX (TeX, really) is *very* picky. A `\vbox` is a vertical object, something like a page, if it complains it means it came up short to exactly fill the space or is too large. Ditto por `\hbox`, a horizontal object typically a line.

If the problems are smallish (and not visible), you can ignore them. Often minor margin overruns can be fixed by rearranging a paragraph, use different wording, or such. The vertical complaints are often due to asking to place a figure or table where it doesn't fit, or asking for pages of the exact same length.