# Can't get rid of Overfull \hbox warning using minipage

Tags: formatting, warnings, layout

I was given a template of a title page that uses `minipage` to position some text and logos. Unfortunately it throws Overfull \hbox warnings, that I can't get rid of.
I broke it down to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parindent 0em
\LARGE\textbf{Long title of my thesis which will pro\-ba\-bly be a little bit more than one line}
\vspace{24pt}\\
by\\
My Name \\[1.5cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
      \LARGE\textbf{A}\\
      \LARGE February
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
      \LARGE\textbf{B}\\
      \LARGE March
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I tried changing this using `\sloppy` and `\fussy` with no success. Also there is another overfull \hbox warning with my title. I tried getting rid of that one using hyphenation as shown in the MWE, but as you can see, I wasn't successfull here either.
Since I was given this template, I don't want to change the output significantly, but I don't want to keep getting this warning. Why is this snippet throwing the \hbox warning and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you really have that piece of text before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @egreg sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Add `%` after the first `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @egreg Interesting. It fixed the problem. What does that change?

Comment: @egreg sorry --- I wrote the answer before seeing your comment...

Comment: @Max You're asking for a line consisting of 40% text, *a space* and 60% text: this is overfull. Where does the space come from? From the line break in the input, which produces a space; with `%` the endline is not seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\overfullrule=5pt` to see where the overfull box is:

[image]

and the problem is that you have two minipages that sum `\textwidth` *separated by 1 space* (the new line at the end of the first). Just using a comment solve it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\overfullrule=5pt
\begin{document}
\parindent 0em
\LARGE\textbf{Long title of my thesis which will pro\-ba\-bly be a little bit more than one line}
\vspace{24pt}\\
by\\
My Name \\[1.5cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
      \LARGE\textbf{A}\\
      \LARGE February
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}% <---- HERE 
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
      \LARGE\textbf{B}\\
      \LARGE March
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there something for detection of underfull boxes, too? Because, even though your fix fully did the work on my MWE, in my actual document the lines before the minipage are throwing an underfull hbox warning.

Comment: Much more difficult. Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21139/how-to-visualize-the-underfull-box-in-final-output-pdf-files

Comment: alright, I'll look for it myself, thanks for the link.